# The difference between vector and deque

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, deque

As `vector` and `deque` both provides a function to `push_back` the element at the last.

where `deque` also provides a function `push_front` to insert the element at the beginning, which is bit costly in case of `vector`.

My question is when we can achieve the same functionality (`push_back`) of `vector` by using `deque`, then why `vector` is required?

Answer (score 24):

One main difference between vectors and deques is that the latter allows efficient insertion at the *front* of the structure as well as the back.

Deques also do not guarantee that their elements are contiguous in memory so the at-style operator (indexing) may not be as efficient.

Note that the difference is unlikely to matter in practice for smaller collections but would generally become more important if, for example, the collection size increases or you're modifying it *many* times per second.

Comment: [So does a `std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/operator_at).

Comment: Efficient insertion depends.  If there aren't too many elements, and they aren't too expensive to copy, inserting at the front can be cheaper in `std::vector` than in `std::deque`.

Comment: @James, if your structures contain only few elements, you may as well use an array and not bother with collections at all :-) I was thinking more along the lines of larger collections where it's more likely that a deque will be more efficient for front insertion. But you raise a good point so I'll add it.

Comment: @paxdiablo The question is: when does a container become large enough to justify the difference.  A very long time ago, I had a colleague who measured the time necessary to shift a million bytes, and it was surprisingly low (but cache memory and potential misses didn't come into play then).  In the end, I don't have any real answer: for 10 `char`, use a C style array or `std::vector` (or `std::array` in C++11).  For millions of elements which do a deep copy (with allocation, etc.), use `std::deque`.  Somewhere in between is the break off line, but I have no idea where.

Comment: @paxdiablo Arrays are used when you know the exact number of elements at compile time.  Other than in some borderline cases (such as trivial types), arrays cannot replace either vector or deque when the number of elements is determined at run time.

Comment: Agreed, Nevin, though in reality, arrays are good if you know the _maximum_ rather than exact size.  If you know the collection will never be larger than (eg) 10, arrays _may_ even be faster than a vector since you could access it directly rather than through class functions (or it may not, depending on the code generated).

Comment: @paxdiablo I implemented a FIFO structure of 100 elements that is used to buffer some input sensor data. I implemented with deque by pushing back new incoming elements and popping the front when the size of 100 is reached. Do you think this is an acceptable architectural choice? Yes, I'm modyfing it many time per second. I wanted to know your opinion about which would be a better approach to realize a First In First Out structure that is used to buffer sensor data. Thank you in advance

Comment: @Lossofhumanidentity: your word "many" may not be the same as my word (italicised) *"many"* :-) If it's a true FIFO, you don't really need to worry about indexing so discount that. Then it's really just a matter of seeing how many inserts per second you can handle. Example, let's say you're sampling rate is 100Hz. All you really need is to dummy up data to pump in an item 100 times a second and see how your processing code handles it. If it never gets anywhere close to 100% capacity, it should be fine.

Comment: Note that if you are keeping pointers to the elements, you must use vector as deque will be moved, rendering the pointers invalid.

Answer (score 13):

Performance, mainly.  An `std::deque` has all of the
functionality of `std::vector`, at least for normal use, but
indexing and iterating over it will typically be somewhat
slower; the same may hold for appending at the end, if you've
used `reserve`.  And of course, `std::vector` is the default
container, using anything else will suggest to the reader that
you have special requirements.

`std::vector` also guarantees contiguity, so it (and only it)
can be used to interface legacy functions which require a `T*`
or a `T const*`.

I might add that the one time I actually had a performance
issue, and measured, `std::vector` was faster than `std::deque`,
*despite* the fact that I was regularly removing elements from
the front (using the container as a queue, pushing at the back,
and popping at the front).  I don't know if that generalizes,
however; in my case, the queue was relatively short (never more
than about 15 elements, and usually many less), and the contents
were `char`, which is extremely cheap to copy.  But in general,
I'd use `std::vector` even if I needed to remove elements from
the front, if only because of its better locality.  I'd probably
only consider `std::deque` if I expected thousands of elements,
which were expensive to copy.

Comment: I implemented a FIFO structure of 100 elements that is used to buffer some input sensor data. I implemented with deque by pushing back new incoming elements and popping the front when the size of 100 is reached. Do you think this is an acceptable architectural choice? I wanted to know your opinion about which would be a better approach to realize a First In First Out structure that is used to buffer sensor data. Thank you in advance

Comment: @Employee it will function but is not as ideal for a FIFO as a vector. Since FIFO are ordered and sequential just as Vectors are, they are a better general pairing. However if you are going to change the order of items in the FIFO pipe *after* building the list, then deque may be appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

`std::deque` is a double-ended queue. It provides efficient insertion and deletion of elements at the beginning also, not just at the end, as `std::vector` does. Vectors are guaranteed to store the elements in a contiguous storage, therefore you can access its elements by index/offset. `std::deque` does not offer this guarantee.

Comment: You can also access elements of a `deque` using `[]` or `at()`.  There's no difference in the interface at that level.